# Infopath Make button works on View Item mode (Sharepoint)

Tags: button, sharepoint, infopath

I've an infopath form that uses picture buttons to switch to different views.

In edit mode everything works allright but I would like to use my buttons also on "read-only" views like "View Item" from sharepoint.

MS says that we can use Picture Button to do so, but in my case the button is displayed but it doesn't do anything, it's like a static picture.
(cf. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-HA101732801.aspx#_Toc260325721 at the end of "Add a button for switching views" section.)

Does somebody expected this problem too or have a solutions?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Switch Views" rule action must be the only rule associated with the Picture Button. Is this the case? Also, it will be helpful to know what rule you are attaching to the button.

Here's a more detailed guide from Microsoft, maybe it'll have something the other is missing?
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/infopath-help/add-a-button-for-switching-views-HP010211230.aspx